# C++ template instance as function parameter and lambda binary predicate

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

I am in the process of fixing some of the sonarcloud issues on my project. One complaint is the function where I read and deserialize the settings for my application. Basically there are 50 or so blocks of this in one function:

```
if (!m_logLevel.deserializeFromSettings(settings, HGGW_KEY_LOGLEVEL) || m_logLevel.value() <= 0 || m_logLevel.value() > 4)
    {
        m_logLevel.update(HGGW_DEFAULT_LOGLEVEL, 0);
        m_logLevel.serializeToQSettings(settings, HGGW_KEY_LOGLEVEL);
    }
```

The members are instances of a templated class:

```
template <typename T>
class AwsProperty
{
public:
    AwsProperty(T value, qint64 timestamp) : m_timestamp(timestamp), m_data(value){}
    //other stuff, not important
}
//example:
AwsProperty<int> m_property;
```

I tried to design this function:

```
template <typename X>
    void readAWSSettingOrPopulateDefault(AwsProperty<X> property, QString key, X default_val, QSettings settings, bool (*predicate)(X)){
        if(!property.deserializeFromSettings(settings,key) || predicate(property.value())){
            property.update(default_val, 0);
            property.serializeToQSettings(settings, key);
        }
    }
```

Trying to call it:

```
    this->readAWSSettingOrPopulateDefault(m_logLevel, HGGW_KEY_LOGLEVEL, HGGW_DEFAULT_LOGLEVEL, settings, [](int val){return val <= 0 || val > 4;});
```

Yields this error:

```
XXXXconfig.cpp:275: error: no matching function for call to ‘LocalConfig::readAWSSettingOrPopulateDefault(HGGWAwsPropertyInt32&, const QString&, const int&, QSettings&, LocalConfig::init(QString)::<lambda(int)>)’
     this->readAWSSettingOrPopulateDefault(m_logLevel, HGGW_KEY_LOGLEVEL, HGGW_DEFAULT_LOGLEVEL, settings, [](int val){return val <= 0 || val > 4;});
XXXXconfig.cpp:275: note:   mismatched types ‘bool (*)(X)’ and ‘LocalConfig::init(QString)::<lambda(int)>’
     this->readAWSSettingOrPopulateDefault(m_logLevel, HGGW_KEY_LOGLEVEL, HGGW_DEFAULT_LOGLEVEL, settings, [](int val){return val <= 0 || val > 4;});
                                                                                                                                                   ^                                                                                                                                                   ^
                                                                                                                                                   XXXXconfig.cpp:275: note:   mismatched types ‘bool (*)(X)’ and ‘LocalConfig::init(QString)::<lambda(int)>’
                                                                                                                                                   ^
```

Comment: How can I uses the templated class as a function parameter and also a binary lambda predicate?

Comment: @JeJo I added my attempt at solving it to the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code reports an error is that for a function template declared as:

```
template <typename X>
void readAWSSettingOrPopulateDefault(AwsProperty<X> property, QString key
                                   , X default_val, QSettings settings
                                   , bool (*predicate)(X));
```

the compiler will have to deduce `X` from all arguments using this template parameter -- `property`, `default_val` *and* `predicate` -- and then  make sure that those deduced types are the same (that is, there's only one template parameter, it can hold one type).

However, a lambda *is not* a function. It is *convertible* to a function pointer through an implicit conversion. Template argument deduction does not consider conversions (except for the derived-to-base conversion). Hence, the compiler is unable to finalize template argument deduction.

In order to make your code work, put the last occurrence of `X` in the function pointer-type parameter declaration in a *non-deduced context*:

```
template <typename T>
struct dont_deduce { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
using dont_deduce_t = typename dont_deduce<T>::type;

template <typename X>
void readAWSSettingOrPopulateDefault(AwsProperty<X> property, QString key
                                   , X default_val, QSettings settings
                                   , bool (*predicate)(dont_deduce_t<X>));
```

This way, the compiler will not even attempt to deduce `X` from the lambda expression, and instead will use the type from `property`/`default_val`, thus making it possible to use the implicit conversion of the lambda to a function pointer. That is, no deduction and at the same time, a known function signature that can trigger the conversion.

Comment: I added my attempt at doing in the opening post, its similar to yours but only uses one generic template type. Do you see why compiler complains about the lambda matching?

Comment: Thank you so much, after a bit of research I found out that this will be part of C++2X.

Comment: @Curunir Yes, it's a replacement for `std::type_identity_t`